# Sync to Outlook 2010 with redemption in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, outlook-redemption

I am developing an application where I want to sync the outlook calendar, mail, etc.
The piece of code which is there with me is working fine for outlook 2003, 2007.
but I don't know what's the problem it is causing for outlook 2010.
I use the following:

redemption dll 5.4 version-32 bit
office object core 14 dll-32 bit
office -32 bit version
visual studio 2008

I am getting this error:

> Cannot create ActiveX component.

On the following line:

```
session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
```

Where session is:

```
Dim session As Redemption.RDOSession
```

After which the following error is displayed:

> Either there is no default mail client or the current mail client cannot fulfill the messaging request

I have tried [various things](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/813745) but it's same. I also reinstalled, repaired outlook, repaired registry.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me:

first, I will say I used the Customize.exe that comes with redemption to create a dll called ffloader.dll

Next, I registered that dll as follows (32 bit)
regsvr32 ffloader.dll

Finally in the vb.net code I created the session as follows:

Dim Session As Redemption.RDOSession = CreateObject("ffloader.ffRDOSession")

Hope that helps!